# tomcat + nginx 502 error(104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: tomcat, nginx, bad-gateway

I'm using nginx + tomcat.

Intermittent nginx 502 errors occur.

The error.log contents are as follows.

```
2019/10/08 06:40:54 [error] 52996 # 0: * 25112952 recv () failed (104: 
Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 
00.000.000.00, server: aaa.bbb. ccc, request: "POST / servlet / AAServlet HTTP / 
1.1", upstream: "http://111.111.111.111:8888/servlet/AAServlet", host: 
"aaa.bbb.ccc: 1234", referrer: "https: //qqq.www.eee/test.do "
```

The nginx configuration is as follows:

```
        **nginx.conf**

        worker_processes 2;
        error_log logs / error.log notice;
        events {
            worker_connections 1024;
        }

        http {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            underscores_in_headers on;
            server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            include mime.types;
            default_type application / octet-stream;
            log_format lf '$ remote_addr, "$ time_local", "$ request_uri", $ status, $ request_time,
            $ body_bytes_sent';
            sendfile on;
            keepalive_timeout 15;
            error_page 400 401 403 402 404 405 = /error/50x.html;
            include vhosts / test.conf;
        }

        **test.conf**

        upstream test.ssl.web {
            ip_hash;
            server 111.111.111.111:8000 max_fails = 3 fail_timeout = 30s;
            server 111.111.111.112:8000 max_fails = 3 fail_timeout = 30s;
        }
        server {
            listen 443;
            server_name aaa.bbb.com;
            access_log logs / test.443.access.log lf;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_read_timeout 80s;
            proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
            proxy_buffers 1024 1024k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
            client_body_buffer_size 1024k;
            server_tokens off;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate XXXXX;
            ssl_certificate_key XXXXX;
            ssl_session_timeout 5m;
            ssl_protocols XXXXX;
            ssl_ciphers XXXXX;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        
            location / {
                root html;
                index index.html index.htm;
                limit_except GET POST {
                  deny all;
                }
                proxy_pass http://test.ssl.web/;
            }
        }
```

1. The server is not busy.
2. The nginx 502 error is displayed (in the error log, 104: Connection reset by peer).
3. Normal operation upon reload.
4. I've changed but it's the same.

```
    worker_connections 1024-> 2048
    keepalive_timeout 15-> 80
    max_fails = 3 fail_timeout = 30s-> 3, 10
```